How do I search for !A on Google in 2024?
I would like to search for the exact phrase !A on Google. However this does not work. When I type in "!A", I get just the results for the letter A. How can I find the results that have an exclamation mark in front of it?
I am using a Windows computer and would like the application to be free. Is there, for example a Python script that I can use?
